# Getting text information from the Internet into my app

Tags: objective-c

I learning Objective C, and I am going to develop some apps. I have a general question: How to get text information from the Internet into your app. Say you want the current title of Yahoo News. Do I need to use some PHP, or are there Objective-C specific classes to choose from?

Help is appreciated (code as well!), just anything that can help me take te step to exploring the new possibilities!

Comment: What do you mean by using some PHP? You'd like to pass the task to a server side script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a great way to do it:

1. **Go to [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/)**, and create your "pipe" (basically a feed of one or many different data inputs on the web).
2. **Publish**: Select a format for Yahoo to host, for example as an RSS feed or in JSON.
3. **UIWebView** can then point to your pipe's URL. (Here's a tutorial on [UIWebView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/iPhoneDevReader.aspx))

Done.

*Note that you can choose to get the feed as RSS, JSON, and other formats as well. Here is an example of a pipe I set up for the [National Vulnerabilities Database](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=15d984c86034633ed9efdedb2e709536&_render=rss) as RSS, and the [same feed as JSON](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=15d984c86034633ed9efdedb2e709536&_render=json).*

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, I'd say the best way to do it would be to get the HTML source from the URL of your choosing as a string, then parse it to grab an attribute such as the title. Have a look at [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) and [NSXMLDocument](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html); they both let you instantiate them from a URL.

Comment: Thanks to you too! I found exactly that out just hours ago! Now I have another question, hoe to parse the useful part of the superlong string into smaller useful strings. Look at my other question.

Answer (score 0):

[ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) Will keep you sane.